# is there way to reduce the space for text in a NSTextfield in swift xcode

Tags: swift, cocoa

what i'd like to do is deduce the text space inside of a NSTextfield
so basically leaving a white space of a certain size at the end of the textfield rather than the text going all the way to the limit of the textfield and breaking the line

is there a way to do this programatically?

update:
i'm looking for a way to set it directly via the property not via subclassing ect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSTextField margin and padding? (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906160/nstextfield-margin-and-padding-swift)

Comment: no its not that i needed padin